# Pushing custom updates to Ubuntu remixes

Tags: updates, launchpad, custom-distributions

I've created a custom distribution of Ubuntu (a "remix") that I'd like to start distributing, but want to continue improving via updates.

Any suggestions on the best methods of pushing custom updates?  Mainly looking to add new packages and run scripts.

Launchpad?  Different approach?

Answer (score 0):

PPA is a great approach if your packages are suitable for endorsement.

If you're using sub-par packages, but you still want to have a repo I found an interesting article on hosting a repo on Amazon S3 [here](http://xn.pinkhamster.net/blog/tech/host-a-debian-repository-on-s3.html).